# Is it possible to cycle from Manhattan to Williamsburg, Brooklyn on cycle paths only?

Tags: new-york-city, bicycles

Is it possible to cycle from Manhattan to Williamsburg, Brooklyn on cycle paths only?  Or do you need to ride on normal roads as well?

Comment: You want theory or reality?  And it might possibly be better suited for bicycle.SE.  Also where in Manhattan are you starting from?

Comment: Probably from the Intrepid sea musem (12th Avenue & 46th Street)

Comment: Theoretically it's possible: https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Intrepid+Sea,+Air+%26+Space+Museum,+New+York,+NY&daddr=Williamsburg+Bridge,+Manhattan,+NY&hl=en&ll=40.712801,-73.965476&spn=0.011515,0.016866&sll=40.73373,-73.97644&sspn=0.184188,0.269852&geocode=FT0EbgId79yW-yHxP3RStmIjAimfGWDVTljCiTHxP3RStmIjAg%3BFfI9bQIdYUSX-yFg82I73d2T2ykPovfj11vCiTFg82I73d2T2w&oq=williamsburg&dirflg=b&mra=ls&t=m&z=16&lci=bike Practically you have to deal with cabs/people blocking the lanes and a simple lack of bicycle lanes on the streets.

Comment: Please consider [checking with the Bicycles.SE community](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome) before migrating questions there. In particular, the [community there is fairly picky about routing questions](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2/suggesting-bike-routes-allowed).

Answer (score 2):

Technically yes, because the Williamsburg bridge has a cycle path?

But in reality, it all depends on where you are going from/to. Check here to map yourself a route: http://www.nycbikemaps.com/maps/nyc-bike-map/